# Всегда, во все века, есть истина одна —/:/, что дружба на земле сильней всего

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно?

> Всегда, во все века, есть истина одна — что дружба на земле сильнее всего.

> Всегда, во все века, есть истина одна: что дружба на земле сильнее всего.

> Всегда, во все века, есть истина одна, что дружба на земле сильнее всего.

Comment: Минусую за речевую ошибку: дружба *сильнее всего*... Потому что чепуха, исправляйте, Леопольд Метрович.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Всегда, во все века, есть истина одна, что дружба на земле сильней всего* — пауза небольшая, запятая разделяет однородные определения (определительное придаточное и определение *одна*);

*Всегда, во все века, есть истина одна — что дружба на земле сильней всего* — пояснительные отношения; пауза побольше; придаточное определительное выполняет функцию пояснения;

*Всегда, во все века, есть истина одна: что дружба на земле сильней всего* — пауза еще больше, чем у тире.

Самые желательные варианты — с двоеточием и с тире. При необходимости тире можно заменить на двоеточие, для, возможно, большей выразительности и чтобы показать, что здесь большая пауза.

Comment: Максим, утомили уже своими паузами, хотелось бы немного семантики и грамматики. СПП, знаки неосновные. Где правила и ссылки на Розенталя? Это не решение!  (Можно еще стилистики добавить.) Запятая, кстати, не подходит, а почему?  Интонационный анализ вам мешает работать, но пока не помогает.